# Desperately looking for a working example of this MVC modal dialog validation pattern

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a grid. When the user clicks on a link in one of the rows, I have to take that row ID and prompt the user for a date parameter in a modal dialog. I need to do a server call to validate that the date input entered in the dialog is appropriate for the row ID that was originally clicked. If not valid, display error in the dialog, else, submit row ID and date to perform a controller action the specified RowId and Date as parameters.

The perfect example would be where the contents of the dialog were built using a server partial view and the dialog box is updated using Ajax to avoid a full screen refresh.

I'm using C#, MVC 5, jQuery, JQueryUI and would like to avoid other examples using additional frameworks.

I've seen examples that do various things, but none that do everything in this pattern. I'm really anxious to get a working example that I can download. I just can't seem to put all the pieces together of the various examples that I've seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy and paste the example below as is.I'm using bootstrap for the modal popup(I really like it and prefer it over the jQuery UI dialog), if you want to change it then it's up to you.The rest of the logic does exactly what you asked for.

**Controller:**

```
namespace MVCExample.Controllers
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExampleController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var p1 = new Person { ID = 1, Name = "P1" };
            var p2 = new Person { ID = 2, Name = "P2" };
            var people = new List<Person> { p1, p2 };

            return View(people);
        }

        public PartialViewResult _GetPartialView(string date)
        {
            ViewBag.Date = date;
            return PartialView("~/Views/Example/_Partial.cshtml");
        }

        public JsonResult ValidateDate(int id, string date)
        {
            //Validate your date here and return appropriate response...
            return Json(new { IsValid = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

**_Partial.cshtml view:**

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;margin-top:5px;">
    <p>Thank you.Your request for Date - @ViewBag.Date has been received!</p>
</div>
```

**Index view:**

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCExample.Controllers.Person>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var _id = null;

        $(".enterDate").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            _id = id;
            $("#modal").modal('show');
            $('#response').empty();
        });

        $("#btnOK").click(function () {
            $('#response').empty();
            var date = $("#myDate").val();
            if (date != "" && _id != null) {
                alert("Going to the server to check if the date is valid - " + date + ".ID - " + _id);
                $.getJSON("/Example/ValidateDate?id=" + _id + "&date=" + date, function (data) {

                    debugger;
                    if (data.IsValid == true) {
                        alert("The date appears to be valid. Going to the server again to fetch a partial view.");

                        $.get("Example/_GetPartialView?date=" + date, function (data) {
                            $('#response').html(data);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="enterDate" data-id="@item.ID">Enter date</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<!--This is the modal popup-->
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Please select date</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="date" id="myDate" />
                <input type="button" id="btnOK" value="OK" />
                <div id="response"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image: Making ajax calls from ASP.NET MVC and returning partial view inside a modal dialog]

Comment: you response is good because is for a desperate man, but you know your code in your view can be improved put the scripts to the end to don't block the render of your HTML right?

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. It was just what I was looking for and I was able to get it working. Note that I had to add a leading forward slash before the word "Example" on your GET statement.